# Syntax check fails on array as parameter to sub

Tags: arrays, vba, max

I have two related problems. It seems like I don't have a library attached. I have searched and cannot find what I am missing. This is a call to a sub from a function that is called(referenced) in an Excel cell.
The syntax checker fails when I put an array in as a parameter like this which is taken from this [VB Page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/arrays/)

```
Sub EmptyValid210917 _
  (RefData As String, RefRow As Integer, PhraseArray As String(,), _
  DayIndex As Integer, EmptyCol As Boolean, ValidCol As Boolean)
```

The second related issue is the syntax check fails when I try to dim an array like this:

```
Dim ColOffset(,) As Integer
```

It will accept this:

```
Dim ColOffset(2, 2) As Integer
```

But does not accept loading as below which is taken from this [VB Guide How To](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/arrays/how-to-initialize-an-array-variable)

```
Dim ColOffset(2, 2) As Integer = {{1,2},{3,4}}
```

Perhaps this is also related. When I call the max function. I get: Compile Error - Method or data member not found

```
FirstValidDay = Math.Max(1, 2)
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I believe that article is for VB, not VBA. Try reading [this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/declaring-arrays) instead. Your sub should look like this `Sub EmptyValid210917 (RefData As String, RefRow As Integer, PhraseArray() As String, DayIndex As Integer, EmptyCol As Boolean, ValidCol As Boolean)` and you can declare an array like this `Dim ColOffset() As Integer` if you do not know the dimension beforehand or needs to be flexible which allows you to `ReDim` at a later point or `Dim ColOffset(2, 2) As Integer` if it's fixed at 2x2.

Comment: As for your `Max` question - VBA itself does not have a `Max` function but if you are working on Excel, you can use `Application.WorksheetFunction.Max` [method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.max) or `Application.Max` could work too. Otherwise, you can write your own. @jack

Comment: OK, that works, and it does handle the multidimensions inside the sub. The real point of the second issue was that the syntax checker won't accept an initialization 
Dim ColOffset(2, 2) As Integer = {{1,2},{3,4}}
so I have to load an array like this:
ColOffset(1,1) = 1
ColOffset(1,2) = 2
...

Comment: Yes for fixed-size array you will have to do that (perhaps use loop?), for non-fixed array you can use `Array` function but you need to dim like this  `Dim ColOffset() As Variant`. [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/array-function) @Jack

Comment: Do note that the default base for array is 0 so `Dim ColOffset(2, 2) As Integer` actually gives you a 3x3 (and not 2x2 as I said in my previous comment) array.

Comment: Yes, the application.max works also. I cannot find anything with application.max. Would that be running the Excel MAX function? Would that mean all Excel functions are callable with application.xxx?

Comment: OK, yes, I read about using the "Array function" to load dynamic sized arrays, as you can tell I'm just beginning to use VB arrays so I was getting acquainted by using fixed sized arrays. Yes, I found Option Base 1 so I used that since I think more from 1 to n.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't answer you that as I'm don't understand it well enough to advise you, I believe they are the same mostly but different in how they handle error and there's Intellisense if you use `Application.WorksheetFunction`. http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2004/09/24/the-worksheetfunction-method/ @jack

Comment: Thank you Raymond for the daily dose and all your help. Very good! My bedtime now in Los Angeles.